# Tensorflow CPU-only:TypeError: unbound method _as_graph_element() must be called with Variable instance as first argument

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use Tensorflow without GPU, only CPU. I installed it with `pip install tensorflow`.
My Ubuntu17 has Python3, but when I `pip install tensorflow` , It uses Python2.

My code look like this:

```
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
```

I get this error.

```
TypeError: unbound method _as_graph_element() must be called with Variable instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
[Finished in 2.2s with exit code 1]
```

What does this mean? Now I'm trying to use python3 instead, could that help?

Comment: Made the question easier to read. Don't start with the error message, say what you did and tried first, then what didn't work. Try to reduce your problem to the necessary steps. In your example, the code you showed is just one line. It is difficult to debug that because the actual mistake could be how you set up x_image or W_conv1. Include more code, but point out the line where the error is happening. Perfect would be a minimal runnable example of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to understand the error without the context. Maybe your dimensions for either of x_image or W_conv1 are wrong. Maybe you forgot to initialize the weights?

You are more likely to get answers if you add a bit of context (reproducible if possible) code.

Edit: install pip3 and do pip3 install *package* to install python3 packages (if this is also a part of your question)

Comment: my code is just copy from a tutorials from mnist 
 (http://www.tensorfly.cn/tfdoc/tutorials/mnist_pros.html)